# Creating while loop for boolean status of a class method

Tags: ruby, testing, refactoring

I have a class called GuessingGame with a method called `solved?` that returns the state of the game. Everything works inside of here when I run it.

I'm creating some testing code and want to create a loop until the solved method returns true:

```
class GuessingGame
  def initialize(answer)
    @answer = answer
    @solved=false
  end

  def guess(guess_num)
    if guess_num < @answer
      @solved=false
      :low
    elsif guess_num > @answer
      @solved=false
      :high
    elsif guess_num = @answer
      @solved==true
      :correct
    end
  end

  def solved?
      @solved
  end
end
```

The testing code that doesn't work:

```
game = GuessingGame.new(rand(75))
while game.solved? false
  puts "Guess a number between 1-75"
    guess_num=gets.chomp.to_i
  game.guess(guess_num)
end
```

Ruby doesn't like my `while game.solved? false` and is saying I have the wrong number of arguments.

What am I doing wrong here?

I'm running on ruby 2.1.1p76.

Comment: You are calling `solved?`, passing `false` as the argument, but `solved?` doesn't take any arguments. What is it that you are trying to do here?

Answer (score 0):

At the top of your class you need:

```
class GuessingGame
  attr_reader :solved
```

`attr_reader` gives you the ability to call the attributes of that class instance from *outside* the class itself.

From the API doc:

**attr_reader**

> Creates instance variables and corresponding methods that return the
>   value of each instance variable.

From here you can do this:

```
class GuessingGame
  attr_reader :solved
  def initialize(answer)
    @answer = answer
    @solved=false
  end

  def guess(guess_num)
    if guess_num < @answer
      @solved=false
      :low
    elsif guess_num > @answer
      @solved=false
      :high
    elsif guess_num = @answer
      @solved=true
      :correct
    end
  end
end
```

To start the game you just need to modify your code slightly:

```
game = GuessingGame.new(rand(75))
until game.solved
  puts "Guess a number between 1-75"
    guess_num=gets.chomp.to_i
  game.guess_num(guess)
end
```

the `until` loop can be read as until `game.solved = true` keep looping.

I think what you meant to say with `while game.solved? false` was `while game.solved == false`.  `while game.solved == false` would work fine in your scenario.

In my example `until game.solved` is the same as saying `until game.solved == true`, just two different ways to execute the same thing.  Hope that helps!

Comment: The OP already has a method called `solved?` which is being called. It returns `@solved`. Why will adding a getter help?

Comment: Sorry @theTinMan I got called away and only just started my response - didn't quite realize I hit submit.

Answer (score 0):

I'd look at:

```
elsif guess_num = @answer
```

which should be:

```
elsif guess_num == @answer
```

Answer (score 0):

@anthony's solution help a bit, I was able to change my testing code to the following with **until game.solved?**

```
game = GuessingGame.new(rand(75))
until game.solved?
  puts "Guess a number between 1-75"
    guess_num=gets.chomp.to_i
  game.guess(guess_num)
end
```

I also had an incorrect comparison in my class method using = instead of ==

Thank you!